# The number of Sylow Subgroups in a finite solvable group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Could you please help me for the following question:

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_k^{a_k}$. If $G$ is a solvable group can we say that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ must be a prime power $r^\alpha$ for each prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you heard about the third part of Sylow theorem? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order $30=2.3.5$. It consists of $15$ reflections (and $15$ rotations). Each reflection with identity forms a Sylow-$2$ subgroup, resulting in $15=3.5$ Sylow-$2$ subgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: user274480: welcome.